# VBA compile error: Method or data member not found

Tags: vba, excel

everyone. here's my code. When debugging it says "VBA compile error: Method or data member not found" and highlights line: Familienkutsche.strFarbe = "Blau"
If I outcomment it, it says the same thing about the line that follows. What does it not like? Everything is written in one block, so why doesn't he recognize either "strFarbe" or "Geschwindigkeit"? having said that, if I remove Familienkutsche and just leave .strFarbe = "Blau" everything works. Thank you in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Public strFarbe As String
Private bytTempo As Byte
Private blnTempoSperre As Boolean

Public Property Let Geschwindigkeit(Speed As Long)
If (Speed > 250) Then
    bytTempo = 250
    blnTempoSperre = True
Else
    bytTempo = Speed
    blnTempoSperre = False
End If
End Property

Public Property Get Geschwindigkeit() As Long
    Geschwindigkeit = bytTempo
End Property

Public Property Get abgeriegelt() As Boolean
    abgeriegelt = blnTempoSperre
End Property



Public Sub Autos()
Dim Familienkutsche As Auto
Let Familienkutsche = New Auto

Familienkutsche.strFarbe = "Blau"
Familienkutsche.Geschwindigkeit = 320
Debug.Print Familienkutsche.Geschwindigkeit
Debug.Print Familienkutsche.abgeriegelt
End Sub
```

Comment: That wont compile; `Let Familienkutsche = New Auto` should be `Set Familienkutsche = New Auto`

Comment: hi, Alex. Thanks for the quick reply. I made the suggested change but it still doesn't compile and returns the same error. =((((

Comment: Are these codes within a `Class`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your code must be in a **class module** `Auto`.

`Public Sub Autos()` must be in a **standard module**. Then it works (with changing `Let` to `Set`).

Output:

```
 250 
Wahr
```

Comment: Thank you,Andre. That indeed was the issue. I wrote the whole code in another module rather than in the Class Auto one.

Comment: Could you just please explain why exactly the first part and not, say, the second one where I'm actually mentioning New Auto?

Comment: @Lola: you *define* a class in a class module, the module name is the class name - here `Auto`. To actually use the class, you instantiate it (`Set Familienkutsche = New Auto`), this usually happens in a function or sub in a standard module. There are many pages describing this in greater detail, e.g. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx